# Decode a nimbus private class `DerivedColor` into correct ARGB values

Tags: swing, nimbus

I am developing custom components which fit into the Nimbus look and feel. I'm running into a problem with the color defaults which, as with `"nimbusBlueGrey"` in Java 1.6 return instances of `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor`.

Since this is a private class and it would anyway change in Java 7, I need to treat this like an instance of `java.awt.Color`. But when I try to mix the color, e.g. adjust hue, saturation, and brightness, these evil objects return wrong RGB colors. The `toString` output indicates this problem:

```
DerivedColor(color=50,50,50 parent=nimbusBase offsets=0.03245944,-0.525188,0.196078,0)
```

So I want to be able to read this as ARGB `0xffa9b0be` which would be correct (cf. [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)) -- but what I get from `getRGB` is that useless `0x00323232`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when Nimbus *is not the current look and feel*. It seems that `DerivedColor` looks up the current look and feel and then fails to decode the parent color.

So the solution is to use copies of the default colors for the case that Nimbus is not set.